# Merging pandas dataframe indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indices

How can I merge 2 indices

```
index1
Out[8]: Int64Index([22, 23, 24, 25, 32, 33, 34], dtype='int64')

index2
Out[8]: Int64Index([20, 23, 24, 25, 32, 33, 34], dtype='int64')
```

so to obtain

```
index3
Out[8]: Int64Index([20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 32, 33, 34], dtype='int64')
```

that contains the index1 and index2 without duplicates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `union`

```
In [1331]: index1.union(index2)
Out[1331]: Int64Index([20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 32, 33, 34], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the logical OR symbol (`|`) to get the unique set between the two indices.

```
>>> index1 | index2
Int64Index([20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 32, 33, 34], dtype='int64')
```